# partial isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, matrix-calculus, c-star-algebras

If $A\in M_{r\times m}(\mathbb{C}),B\in M_{m\times r}(\mathbb{C})$,$AB=Id_r$,then $A,B$ is a partial isometry.

My question:how to show $A^*A,B^*B$ is a projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. If $m=r=1$, you can take $A=2$, $B=1/2$, and none of them are partial isometries. Even if you require $\|A\|\leq1$, $\|B\|\leq1$, then statements fails: take 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} \tfrac12&\tfrac12\end{bmatrix} B=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
What you can tell from $AB=I$ is that $BA$ is an idempotent: 
$$
(BA)^2=B(AB)A=BA. 
$$
It is not necessary that $BA$ is selfadjoint, though. For instance take 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} \tfrac12&1\end{bmatrix} B=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ \tfrac12\end{bmatrix}.
$$
then $AB=1$, and $BA=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 1\\ 1/4& 1/2\end{bmatrix}$.

You do have that $B^*A^*AB=I_r$, so $AB$ is a partial isometry, and $ABB^*A^*$ is a projection, since 
$$
(ABB^*A^*)^2=ABB^*A^*ABB^*A^*=ABI_rB^*A^*=ABB^*A^*. 
$$

Comment: I saw this conclusion from a book. It states that we can conclude $B$ is injective(view it as a map from $\mathbb{C}^r$ to $\mathbb{C}^m$) and $B$ is a partial isometry and hence $B$ is an isometry.I feel quite confused about it.

Comment: That $B$ is injective, yes. Also, $A$ is surjective. The rest of the conclusions do not hold, as you can see from the examples.

Comment: The proof is about spetral decomposition. It states that if a positive semidefinite matrix P with rank r,for two different representations $P=\sum_{i=1}^r v_iv_i^* =\sum_{j=1}^m w_j w_j^*,$there exists a unique isometry $U=(u_{ij})$ such that $w_i=\sum_{j=1}^r u_{ij}v_j$

Comment: Yes, that result is well-known. But I don't think it's related with what you asked here.

Comment: How to prove the about conclusion.The book states that we can use Douglas factorization theorem to get $AB=Id$,then $U=\bar{B}$ is the isometry we need.

Comment: The proof I know is too long for a comment. I posted the argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3008734/relation-between-different-presentation-of-a-positive-semidefinite-matrix/3008735#3008735).