# Relation between different presentations of a positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

The problem below appears naturally when one tries to discuss uniqueness in the Kraus Decomposition of a completely positive map.

Let $P$ be a positive semidefinite $n\times n$ matrix of rank $r$. Then we may write $$ P=\sum_{j=1}^r v_jv_j^*,\ \ \text{where}\ \ \ v_1,\ldots,v_r\in\mathbb C^n.$$

If we also have $P=\sum_{j=1}^r w_jw_j^*$ for some $w_1,\ldots,w_r\in\mathbb C^n$,

> What's the relation between $v_1,\ldots,v_r$ and $w_1,\ldots,w_r$?

---

**Edit (2024-01-29):** For anyone looking into this, among other places this result appears as Proposition 5.1, in Arveson, *The Probability of Entanglement*, Communications in Mathematical Physics, **286** (2009), 283-312. I very much doubt that this is the first appearance of this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be more succinct. Put together the vectors $v_i$s to form a matrix $V$ and define $W$ analogously. Then both $V$ and $W$ have full column ranks and $VV^\ast=WW^\ast$. Hence $V^\ast x=0$ if and only if $W^\ast x=0$, i.e. the column spaces of $V$ and $W$ have a common orthogonal complement $\mathcal X$. Let $X$ be a matrix whose columns form a basis of $\mathcal X$. Then both augmented matrices $[V|X]$ and $[W|X]$ are invertible. Since $VV^\ast=WW^\ast$, we get $[V|X][V|X]^\ast = [W|X][W|X]^\ast$. Thus $U=[W|X]^{-1}[V|X]$ is a unitary matrix and $V=WU$.

Comment: Very neat. $\ $

Answer (score 1):

The relation is that there exists a unitary $U\in M_r(\mathbb C)$ such that $$w_j=\sum_{k=1}^r U_{jk}v_k.$$

Indeed, fix an orthonormal basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ of $\mathbb C^n$, and we may write 
$$
v_k=\sum_{k=1}^ns_{jk}e_j,\ \ \ w_k=\sum_{j=1}^rt_{jk}e_j.
$$
Now consider $S,T\in M_r(\mathbb C)$ with $S_{kj}=s_{kj}$, $T_{kj}=t_{kj}$. Then 
$$
P=\sum_{k=1}^rv_kv_k^*=\sum_{k=1}^r\sum_{j,\ell=1}^rs_{jk}\overline{s_{\ell k}}e_je_\ell^*=\sum_{k=1}^r\sum_{j,\ell=1}^rS_{jk}{(S^*)_{k \ell}}e_je_\ell^*=\sum_{j,\ell=1}^r(SS^*)_{j\ell}e_je_\ell^*.
$$
Similarly, 
$$
P=\sum_{j,\ell=1}^r(TT^*)_{j\ell}e_je_\ell^*.
$$
As $e_je_\ell^*$ are the matrix units in $M_r(\mathbb C)$, we get that $TT^*=SS^*$. Now we write the polar decompositions 
$$
S^*=W(SS^*)^{1/2},\ \ T^*=V(TT^*)^{1/2},
$$
where  $W,V$ are unitaries. Then $S=(SS^*)^{1/2}W^*$, and 
$$
T=(TT^*)^{1/2}V^*=(SS^*)^{1/2}V^*=SWV^*=SZ,
$$
where $Z=WV^*$. Now 
\begin{align}
w_j&=\sum_{k=1}^r t_{kj}e_k=\sum_{k=1}^r(SZ)_{kj}e_k=\sum_{k,m=1}^rS_{km}Z_{mj}e_k\\ \ \\
&=\sum_{m=1}^r Z_{mj}\sum_{k=1}^rS_{km}e_k=\sum_{m=1}^rZ_{mj}v_m\\ \ \\
&=\sum_{m=1}^rU_{jm}v_m,
\end{align}
where $U=Z^T$.

Comment: By polar decomposition,we have $W,V$ are partial isometries,why  are they unitaries?Besides,the other reprentation of $P$ may have $m(m>r)$ sum of rank 1 matrices.

Comment: If you do the polar decomposition in $M_r(\mathbb C)$, you can always take them to be unitaries. As for $m>r$, enlarge the smallest family with zeroes.